# Imapfilter version 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu 22.04 is supposed to install imapfilter 2.7.5 but on my system Ubuntu installs version 2.6.15. What might be missing on my system that it installs an older version?

I used apt autoclean && apt autoremove to ensure old version was gone followed by apt install imapfilter. Ubuntu was upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.

```
apt policy imapfilter
imapfilter:
  Installed: 1:2.7.5-1build1
  Candidate: 1:2.7.5-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.7.5-1build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
imapfilter -V
IMAPFilter 2.6.15  Copyright (c) 2001-2019 Eleftherios Chatzimparmpas

lua -v
Lua 5.3.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have another version that was installed manually? What is the output of `type -a imapfilter`?

Comment: type -a imapfilter
imapfilter is /usr/bin/imapfilter
imapfilter is /bin/imapfilter

Comment: I also have luarocks installed

Comment: Never mind, to get the later version of imapfilter compiled with lua5.3 or higher, it has to be manually installed not using the apt capability which is compiled with lua5.2